# C++ Converting Vector items to single String Error?

Tags: c++

So I have a function, where `KaylesPosition` is a class with a `vector<int>` called `piles`:

```
// Produces a key to compare itself to equivalent positions     
std::string KaylesPosition::makeKey(){
  std::vector<int> temp(piles.size());
  for (int i = 0;i<piles.size();i++){
    temp[i]=piles[i];
  }

  std::sort (temp.begin(),temp.end());
  std::string key = "" + temp.at(0);
  for (int i=1 ; i<temp.size() ; i++){
    key.push_back('.');
    key.push_back(temp.at(i));
  }

  return key;
}
```

My expected output should be all of the elements in `piles` in order, separated by periods. However instead, I get `key` return as "_M_range_check". I have tried this using std::string.append() and I get either an empty string or a period. How do I get this function to return a string of all of the values in `piles` as expected?

Comment: Curse C++ and its implicit int->char conversions. Something like `key += std::to_string(temp.at(i));` might suit you better. Also, `"" + temp.at(0)` evaluates to a random address, not a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be here:

```
key.push_back(temp.at(i));
```

You are trying to append an integer to a string without getting the string representation of the integer first. Try replacing that line with:

```
key += std::to_string(temp.at(i)); // This will only work if your compiler supports C++11
```

If your compiler doesn't support C++11, try this (don't forget to `#include <sstream>`):

```
std::ostringstream o;
o << temp.at(i);
key += o.str();
```

Or, if you have the option to use Boost (http://boost.org/ ), try its lexical_cast:

```
key += boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(temp.at(i));
```

The reason this code compiled in the first place, is because `push_back` accepts a `char` as its parameter and you're passing an `int` which gets converted to char (although I would expect a warning from the compiler in this case).

P.S.: Same applies for the line

```
  std::string key = "" + temp.at(0);
```

Comment: I don't think compilers issue warnings for implicit int->char conversions.

Comment: Actually it seems to depend on the warning level

Comment: I get nothing from GCC 4.7.2 or VS11 (both my own with warnings cranked up) with this: http://liveworkspace.org/code/f12876f52980fd7b67a52fe164ec8408

Comment: Have you tried setting the warning level to 4 in Visual Studio?

Comment: Indeed I have :/ That implicit conversion is really one we could do without.

Comment: Weird. VS 2010 here, with the following code http://pastebin.com/S5Ls3by2 and warning level 4 I get this warning:  `warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'int' to 'char', possible loss of data`

Comment: That's what I'd expect from GCC with `-Wconversion`, which I have on, but nothing.